# Changing attribute values in a memory layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to change attribute values in a memory layer. My memory layer is defined in this way:

```
pro.addAttributes([QgsField("nom", QVariant.String), QgsField("valeur", QVariant.Int)])
```

I made several tries:

```
attrs = { 0 : "hello"}
bFlag3=vl.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({ fet.id() : attrs })
```

Or in this way :

```
bFlag3=vl.changeAttributeValue(fet.id(),0,'hello')
```

Each time my boolean flag returns **True** but I never see any change in my memory table. I make a

```
vl.commitChanges()
```

in both cases.

When I try these two pieces  of code on the two other layers (which aren't memory layers...) I have in my project, I see the attributes change...

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: In fact i just noticed that i'm not able to (**manually**) modify the fields of this (programmatically created) memory layer in QGIS interface ...
Any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct, but you are missing one line of code:

```
  vl.updateFields()
```

This is not necessary when you edit a layer and then closes it, as it will show correctly when you load it again, but it is necessary if you want to use/see it in the same session.